# Execution of a transformation based on dependencies

Tags: pentaho

I have 3 tables that I want to load in pentaho.  They are three different tables going into three different targets and the third table can not load till the first 2 have loaded.  How do I tell the third transformation/table to wait for the first two?  I'm new to pentaho and I know in Informatica's workflow their is an event wait/raise set of tasks, does pentaho have a similar set of tasks.

Comment: Found similar question in: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26995470/pentaho-spoon-tool-transformation-order .

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

you can use use "**block this step until steps finish**" step under ***flow category*** for achieving your desired output.

Comment: yes i am talking about pentaho spoon.. which version you are using? it is their in pentaho 4.4.0..